# Share completions between running vim instances

Tags: autocompletion, tmux, clientserver

I use `tmux` for the most part instead of using `vim` tabs and splits. Does vim have the ability to share completions (via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>) between running instances? Is there a way to set it up where each of the `vims` are communicating with the server `vim`.?

Comment: No, this can't be done in a *practical* way. Vim is perfectly capable of handling dozens and dozens of buffers, use its power.

Comment: @romainl, could we have something written to a "completion file" from where `vim` would read and refresh its completion list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim is able to use the same completion database if the database is external to each vim instance.

For example, completion will be somewhat 'shared' if you use `ctags` completion or `youcompleteme` or any other plugin that uses external processes or files.

Word completion is not quite useful for you because it will only use words in the same file: `C-N`/`C-P`

But `omni` and `ctags` completion will use `ctags` database (which should be built by `exuberant ctags` beforehand) and will be shared among all instances.

Type `C-X C-O` for omni-completion, `C-X C-]` for ctags completion.

Answer (score 0):

In `:help i_ctrl-n` it shows that Vim uses the `complete` option to complete words. The help on `complete` goes on to show that the only real option to use something that is not local to the Vim instance is to use a dictionary file. The question then boils down to generating such a dictionary file using all vim instances. You could do this by parsing all open files every now and then. I have no idea of the impact this would have on performance though.

Another option would be to use an entirely different mechanic (ctags etc) but this might break functionality elsewhere as these were not really intended for simple autocompletion.

On a more general note, you could also change your workflow a bit to stick more to the way Vim was envisioned to be used. This would mean using one or a few windows to look at stuff simultaneously and switch buffers often. A plugin that does the switching part very nicely is ctrlP. After activating it by pressing a button it allows you to do a fuzzy search for files in various places, thereby allowing quick switching. As long as you remember the filename that is.